# R: How do I convert a date + time of day to a numerical value

Tags: r, date

Each date looks like this:

```
"dd/mm/yy Morning"
```

where the first part is simply the date, and the second part is the time of day, this could also equal any of the following: Afternoon, noon, midnight.

I want to convert each such date into the a numerical number.

First, we are given a baseline date, e.g.

```
"05/05/05 Morning".
```

Then, for every date, I want to calculate the number of days between this date and the baseline date. Further, if our date has the "Morning" tag, then we simply store the integer value as our numerical value. However, if the date has the "Noon" tag, then we add 1/4 to the number.  And if it was Afternoon, we add 2/4, and if it was Midnight, we add 3/4.

So, for example, the date

```
"06/05/05 Midnight",
```

should be converted into 1.75,

while

```
"15/05/05 Morning"
```

should simply be 10.

Any idea how to do this in R?

Comment: `strsplit` then `as.Date` and `match` your keyword. This should be fairly straightforward. i.e. `baseDate<-as.Date("05/05/05",'%d/%m/%y')` then `a = strsplit("06/05/05 Midnight",split = " ")[[1]]` then `as.integer(as.Date(a[1],'%d/%m/%y')-baseDate) + ((0:3)/4)[match(a[2],c('Morning','Noon','Afternoon','Midnight'))]
`

Answer (score 3):

Using stringr and lubridate packages, this function that takes a string of your specified format "dd/mm/yy TimeOfDay" and returns a date-time object (where Morning = 6am, Noon = 12pm, Afternoon = 6pm, Midnight = 12am.

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

unpack <- function(s, tod_levels = c("Morning", "Noon", "Afternoon", "Midnight")) {
  s <- str_split(s, " ")[[1]]
  s_hr  <- as.integer(factor(s[2], levels = tod_levels)) * 6 * 60 * 60
  as_datetime(dmy(s[1])) + s_hr
}
```

Examples using this to prep a baseline and compare to new times:

```
baseline <- unpack("05/05/05 Morning")

unpack("06/05/05 Midnight") - baseline
#> Time difference of 1.75 days

as.numeric(unpack("06/05/05 Midnight") - baseline)
#> [1] 1.75

as.numeric(unpack("15/05/05 Morning") - baseline)
#> [1] 10
```